# Using associative references in categories

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, categories

Although using associative references seems to be the most widely used method to fake category variables, I can't help from thinking of it as a hack. I'm probably wrong. Thus this question. So, I know Apple uses categories for many of the framework classes, and they did so way before 3.1 (when associative references were added). Which makes me wonder, were they doing it in a different way? Are associative references used this way recommended by Apple? (any docs for sustaining this?) From the design point of view, adding storage to a category is something to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associated Objects are **not** a hack, as they are provided to us as standard functions in the ["modern" runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject).

You are right, Associated Objects were not implemented before the "Modern" runtime, however Apple had no use for them.  If they wished to add variables to a class, it was done with a combination of an explicit setter/getter/internal iVar (you'll notice this especially with old Cocoa classes like NSSplitView) in the main class (because why would you need to use associated objects if you owned the framework?)  Apple's use of categories was the old way of grouping similar functions together, something like a language level `#pragma mark -`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While is surely true associative references are not a hack themselves, my though was that used to add storage to a category they feel like a hack. Maybe it has to do with design too. So basically, Apple used categories only for logical grouping keeping the storage in the class. This is different from the behaviour I thought they wanted to achieve, which is plugging in and out certain functionality. Another thing, if adding storage to a category like this is accepted, why don't categories have implicit storage (which could be implemented like this behind the scenes)?

Comment: @Meda define "storage".  If you mean just to store another variable, then yes, they are a little hacky in principle.  Categories were never meant to add properties to classes, only utility methods or extraneous logic that the original framework class shouldn't or didn't implement.

Comment: Starting to make sense, while technical possible and not considered a hack, it somehow defies the whole purpose of the category, which is to add logic, not state. Would you agree with the above?

Comment: @Meda, actually that is probably the most elegant way to put it I've heard in a while.

Comment: Perfect, which made the things clear. Thanks for your time @CodaFi!